# Relation between stereographic projection and 3-Orthogonal group

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $f:\mathbb{S}^2\setminus \{S\}\to \mathbb{C}$ the stereographic projection with respect to the southern pole and $A\in O(3)$ a matrix in the 3-Orthogonal group.

Given $z\in\mathbb{S}^2\setminus {S}$ with $Az=w$, is it possible to relate $f(z)$ and $f(w)$?

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me modify the letters convention for the sake of simplicity :

Let us denote  points on the sphere by upper case letters ($Z,W,\cdots$), and by corresponding lower case letters ($z,w,\cdots$) their resp. images by stereographic projection onto the equatorial plane identified with $\mathbb{C}$.

The answer is affirmative: such a correspondence exists.

To each 3D rotation $Z \mapsto W=RZ$ is attached a unique homography $h$ (more precisely a Möbius transformation) giving $w$ as a function of $z$ :

$$w = h(z)=\dfrac{\ \ uz+v}{-\overline{v}z+\overline{u}}  \ \text{with} \ u,v \in \mathbb{C}  \ \text{such that} \  \  |u|^2+|v|^2=1, \tag{1}$$

itself in correspondence with the following matrix

$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}u&v\\-\overline{v}&\overline{u}\end{array}\right) \ \ \text{with} \ \  |u|^2+|v|^2=1\tag{2}$$

These matrices form a group for matrix product called $SU(2)$ ; there is an isomorphism between $SU(2)$ and the group of homographies defined in (1) for the operation of functions composition. $SU(2)$ is also isomorphic with the group of unit quaternions (see formula (3) in [this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1917093)), this group being currently used in image synthesis, robotics, etc. for working on 3D rotations (closing the loop in a certain way).

But the best, in this spirit, is to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=3D_rotation_group&wteswitched=1#Using_quaternions_of_unit_norm) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

I will not give a true proof but merely explain how it works :

1. **Rotation of angle $\gamma$ around vertical axis** (I don't use the term **$z$ axis** because $z$ is used for complex numbers) is connected  with

$$h_3(z)=e^{i\gamma}z$$

which can be casted into the form (1) as follows :

$$h(z)= \dfrac{e^{i\gamma/2}z+0}{0z+ e^{-i \gamma/2}}$$

2. **Rotation of angle $\beta$ around $y$ axis** is connected with

$$ w:=h_2(z)=\dfrac{\ \ uz+v}{-vz+u} \ \ \ u=\cos(2\beta), \ \ v=\sin(2\beta)$$

(please note angle doubling).

3. Having now the two rotations (with respect to vertical axis and to $y$ axis), we are able to cope with any rotation using ["Euler angles" formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).
4. Exercice : Can you describe the 3D rotation associated with the following homography ?

$$h(z)=\dfrac{\ \ \cos(2\alpha)z-i\sin(2\alpha)}{-i\sin(2\alpha)z+\cos(2\alpha)}$$

> It is plainly the **rotation with angle $\alpha$ around the $x$ axis**. Indeed, the expression above can be decomposed into the 3-steps combination $h_3(iz) \times (-i)$ where 1) $z \mapsto iz$ brings the $x$ axis onto the $y$ axis, 2) $h_2$ operates a rotation around with angle  $\alpha$, 3) the last operation finally puts back the $x$ axis into its original position.

For proofs and presentation, see this [excellent document](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Ewestra/so3su2.pdf) whose formalism is close to ours.

In a slightly different way see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160711) using Pauli matrices. More generally, physicists have a special way of seeing all this (especially for Quantum Mechanics), and sometimes, it is hard to "translate" from/to the mathematicians point of view (it is often a mere question of notation).

Here is an example of use of this correspondence. See Fig. 1 and (a part of) the program that has generated it which is to found at the bottom of this answer. Circles drawn on the sphere, are in fact obtained in a first step in the equatorial plane (assimilated to $\mathbb{C}$), then transferred onto the sphere by (back) stereographic projection.

[image]

*Fig 1. Correspondence by stereographic projection of 2 "necklaces" of circles on the sphere and on the equatorial plane. Please note that we have used here a stereographic projection from North Pole instead of South Pole in order to show more visibly how circles are transformed into circles.*

[image]

*Fig. 2 : Another nice correspondence between a double family of circles on the sphere (meridians and parallels) and on the equatorial plane (family of Apollonian circles and its orthogonal family ; see explanations [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3406280).*

Internet queries : it is advisable to include "SO(3) SU(2)" keyword(s).

Links : [http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/rotate.pdf](http://people.reed.edu/%7Ejerry/311/rotate.pdf)

Remarks : [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group) for understanding more about SU(2) and how it is inserted into a "bigger picture".

**Appendix** : Matlab program for the generation of Fig. 1 :

> ```
> function stereo;
>    clear all,close all;hold on;axis equal;
>    i=complex(0,1);
>    [x,y,z]=sphere(200);surf(x,y,z);alpha(0.6);shading interp;
>    n=12; % number of pearls
>    G=1+i+(3/n)*exp(i*pi*(0:0.01:2));% initial circle
>    neckl(G,n);% plot in equatorial plane and on the sphere 
>    view([152,20]);
> %
> function [X,Y,Z]=sterproj(z);% (from equatorial = complex plane to sphere)
>     d=abs(z).^2+1;
>     X=2*real(z)./d;Y=2*imag(z)./d;Z=(d-2)./d;
> function Z=Ry(z,bet);% homog <-> rotation around Oy
>     B=2*bet;
>     a=cos(B);b=-sin(B);c=-b;d=a;
>     Z=(a*z+b)./(c*z+d);
> function neckl(G,n);
>     for k=0:n-1
>        Z=Ry(G,k*pi/(2*n));
>        plot(real(Z),imag(Z),'r'); % 2D plot
>        [XX,YY,ZZ]=sterproj(Z);
>        plot3(XX,YY,ZZ,'w'); % 3D plot
>     end;
> ```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. But, how I can relate the rotation $R$ and the homography $h$? For example, if we rotate around $z-$axis? Is it possible to relate the matrix $R$ with $h$?